# mysql getting where clause weather the count is 0 or not

Tags: mysql, database, group-by, count

I wanted to show assigned_user_id in the Column User_ID whether the Meeting_Count is 0 or having value.

With below Query I'm getting only

```
+---------+---------------+
| User_ID | Meeting_Count |
+---------+---------------+
| NULL    |             0 |
+---------+---------------+
```

```
SELECT
meeting.assigned_user_id AS User_ID,
COUNT(*) AS Meeting_Count
FROM meeting
WHERE meeting.assigned_user_id = '5c3e31bb4b708eeb5'
AND meeting.date_start >= NOW() - INTERVAL 60 DAY
```

My Requirement is to get as this,

```
+-------------------+---------------+
| User_ID           | Meeting_Count |
+-------------------+---------------+
| 5c3e31bb4b708eeb5 |            0  |
+-------------------+---------------+
```

Can anyone help me on this. I'm still a learner.

Comment: can u provide some sample data of your meeting table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `where` clause filters out rows that do not belong to the given user, resulting in an empty resultset if no row at all matches. One workaround is to move the filtering within a conditional expression. In MySQL, you would phrase this as:

```
select
    '5c3e31bb4b708eeb5' as user_id,
    sum(assigned_user_id = '5c3e31bb4b708eeb5') as meeting_count
from meeting
where date_start >= now() - interval 60 day
```

If there is a possibility that the table contains no rows for the last 60 days, and you still want a result in that case, then you can take on step forward and move the date filtering to the `sum()` as well:

```
select
    '5c3e31bb4b708eeb5' as user_id,
    sum(assigned_user_id = '5c3e31bb4b708eeb5' and date_start >= now() - interval 60 day) as meeting_count
from meeting
```

This is *guaranteed* to always return one row.

It should be noted that conditional aggregation is by nature less efficient than filtering with a `where` clause.

Comment: Hi GMB, Thanks. its working. What If i wanna show more 10 assigned_user_id information ? how that can be added to this ? please h l p

Comment: @Nishan: that's a pretty different question, for which you should provide sample data and desired results, in a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)...

Comment: will do. Thank you for the support!